# ¿Cómo insertar una cierta cantidad de digitos en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de insertar un registro a 3 dígitos, ejemplo: si es el primero que salga 001 y el consecutivo sea 002, al llegar al 10! que salga 010.

en mi código lo que logro es que me lo inserte sin los dos ceros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
declare @Resultado int
SELECT @Resultado = SUBSTRING(MAX(Agente), CHARINDEX('V', MAX(Agente)) + 1, 4) + 1
FROM Agente
WHERE Agente LIKE '%204%'
AND Tipo = 'Agente'

print @Resultado

    insert into Agente
        (Agente, Nombre, Estatus, Conciliar, Nomina, Logico1, Logico2, Equipo)
    values
        ('204V'  + Convert(varchar, @Resultado), 'Lalo Garcia', 'ALTA', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
end
```

Espero me puedan apoyar.

Comment: No tengo mucha experiencia en SQL, pero me parece que no se puede. Además, lo ideal es siempre separar el Dato del Formato, donde esté ultimo lo adecuas solo cuando muestras aquel Dato

Comment: Rayos!! y con c# se puede? Si se puede alguna documentación que me recomiendes para basarme en ello.

Comment: Claro que se puede. Según el framework que uses (MVC, WPF, win forms, etc), puede ser más automatico o no. Pero en general, para todos sirve: numero.ToString("000") o string.Format("{0:000}", numero)

Comment: de que tipo es agente? @Yussef si es un texto, se puede hacer cualquier cosa.. aunque no deberia...

Comment: @gbianchi Entiendo que se refiere al ID de la primera columna

Comment: @Yussef me suena a que el id ese es el numero de fila.. pero todo puede ser jajajaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una solución simple.

Tienes una variable númerica, como receptor del número que proviene de una consulta. Luego si a una variable de tipo cadena rellenada con 3 ceros y concatenando lo que tiene la númerica, le dejas solo los 3 caracteres de la derecha, ya tienes los ceros por delante.

```
Declare @resultado int = 1;
Declare @cadena varchar(6);
Set @cadena = Concat('000',Cast(@resultado as varchar(3)));
Set @cadena = RIGHT(@cadena,3);

Select @cadena;
```

[image: Res1]

En tú código.

```
declare @Resultado int;
Declare @cadena varchar(6);

SELECT @Resultado = SUBSTRING(MAX(Agente), CHARINDEX('V', MAX(Agente)) + 1, 4) + 1
FROM Agente
WHERE Agente LIKE '%204%'
AND Tipo = 'Agente'

print @Resultado

Set @cadena = Concat('000',Cast(@resultado as varchar(3)));
Set @cadena = RIGHT(@cadena,3);

    insert into Agente
        (Agente, Nombre, Estatus, Conciliar, Nomina, Logico1, Logico2, Equipo)
    values
        ((Concat('204V',@cadena)) , 'Lalo Garcia', 'ALTA', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

[Dar a números formato factura](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/04/dar-formato-numeros-tipo-factura-00005/)

**Nota**: Se supone que solo puede contener 3 dígitos, y por eso la variable cadena se crea con un varchar(6). Si puede contener más, entonces tendrás que dimensionarla con un tamaño mayor y controlar los caracteres a escoger por la función right.

Comment: Javi, muchas gracias! funciono muy bien.